# Google sheets API append method (last on top)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When using google sheets api append method (in any language), the values to be appended to the sheet are added after the last non null row.
So new values appear at the bottom of the sheet, as explained here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#InsertDataOption

How can I append values in a way that the new values appear at the top of the sheet?

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have issues in my answer, feel free to tell me. Such information helps me to study. Also I think that it helps other users to know the situation as an information.

Comment: Thank so much @Rubén

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to append values by inserting new rows. If my understanding is correct, how about this method? It seems that `sheets.spreadsheets.values.append` appends values to the last row. So I would like to propose to use`sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate`. The endpoint and request body are as follows. When you use this, please modify `### spreadsheet ID ###`, `"sheetId": 1234567890` and the parameters for range and values.

#### Endpoint :

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/### spreadsheet ID ###:batchUpdate
```

#### Request body :

```
{
 "requests": [
  {
   "insertRange": {
    "range": {
     "sheetId": 1234567890,
     "startRowIndex": 0,
     "endRowIndex": 1
    },
    "shiftDimension": "ROWS"
   }
  },
  {
   "pasteData": {
    "data": "sample1, sample2, sample3",
    "type": "PASTE_NORMAL",
    "delimiter": ",",
    "coordinate": {
     "sheetId": 1234567890,
     "rowIndex": 0,
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

#### Flow of this request :

1. Insert new row to row 1 using "insertRange".
2. Import values of "sample1, sample2, sample3" using "pasteData".

When the order of "insertRange" and "pasteData" is changed, at first, the value of "A1:A3" is overwritten. After this, the new row is inserted to the row 1. So it seems that the elements of "requests" which is an array run in the order.

#### Reference :

- [sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike , will give it a shot and let you know

Comment: @Tlink Thank you for your response. I will wait for it.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for your helpful answer! Could you please add an alternative of adding multiple rows, similar to append, which accepts an array of row arrays?
pasteData accepts only 1 string parameter (1 row with column values separated by comma), would like array of arrays.